# Can't Open File/Program with cmd.exe when connected via SSH (but works locally)

Tags: windows-10, ssh, cmd.exe

First off, let me say that I'm a Windows neophyte. I'm not nearly as dumb when it comes to the Mac and Debian but the Windows world is basically a mystery to me so please be gentle. Anyways, here's the issue. I'm trying to do something which is seemingly very simple--open a file on a remote Windows 10 machine from my Mac when connected via SSH.

When I'm on the Windows machine locally, I can accomplish this many different ways. Directly using cmd.exe, via a .bat file, double clicking on it (obviously) but whenever I connect over SSH and try to do the same thing, it looks like it's working but nothing...

For reference, I've successfully managed to quit the app I'm trying to open and also to open a different app using:

```
psexec /i Restart64.exe
```

but trying to open this one particular file just doesn't work for some reason.

Obviously I've installed Open SSH server, can connect (using my private key) and I can actually do exactly what I want with a .PNG file by just calling it from cmd (it opens up right up on the remote machine as expected). However, no matter which way I try, when I try to open a file using a third party app, nothing happens. I've tried with PsExec, I've tried with cmd.exe, by incorporating the arguments in a .bat file and launching those (using both of the aforementioned methods), and I've even tried with Bash. Nothing works.

I get the feeling that some sort of security mechanism is at work here but I just don't know what. I've done hours of research on this and it seems that other people have similar issues, but nothing I've tried has worked. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

After some additional experimentation I, a) still am not clear why this problem occurs (although I have a theory which is irrelevant here) and b) have figured out how to work around it. So here it is:

As I posted in my question, I was able to launch the app I wanted using a batch file. I thought that if I was able to launch that batch file with a Task Scheduler task, I *might* be able to manually launch that task on demand over ssh. That theory turned out to be correct. I'm sure there's probably a way to do what I want to do directly in Task Scheduler, but at this point, I'm over this problem even though the solution is a little inelegant. So, in short the solution was:

1) Create batch file to open file using the application I want.

2) Create a task in Task Scheduler to open the batch file

3) SSH in from my remote machine and run

`SCHTASKS.EXE /RUN /TN "task name"`

That's it!